# Как поделить страницу сайта?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как поделить сайт как на картинке? Серый круг это первая часть а белое это вторая.
Тоесть поделить сайт на две части но обводку сделать выпуклой? Если можно или код или сыллку на видео-урок.

[image: Серый круг это первая часть а белое это вторая.]

Comment: https://vk.com/create_it_studio?z=photo-167225333_457239110%2Falbum-167225333_00%2Frev вот как тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде бы оно

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: ;
  padding: 0 0 0 20em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.el{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background:#00a8ff;
  border-radius: 90%;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-block{
  width: 100%;
}

@media(max-width: 950px){
  .text{
    padding: 0 10em;
  }

  h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  p{
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
<svg viewBox="0 0 900 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill='#00a8ff'/>
  <circle cx="900" cy="230" r="100%" fill="#fff">
</svg>
<div class="text">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="el">
      lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-block">
    <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit vitae nobis veritatis laboriosam placeat vel alias corrupti ipsa nostrum inventore?</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можете через радиальный градиент сделать

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse 100% 150% at left, #AFAFAF 50%, transparent 50%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```